# parse HEX value from a string

Tags: regex, tcl

I am trying to get a hex value from a string with this condition "VALUE: num,num,num,HEX,num,num"

I have the following

```
% set STRINGTOPARSE "VALUE: 12,12,13,2,9,5271256369606C00,0,0" 
% regexp {(,[0-9A-Z]+,)+} $STRINGTOPARSE result1 result2 result3
1
% puts $result1
,12,
% puts $result2
,12,
% puts $result3
```

I believe the condition of {(,[0-9A-Z]+,)+} will be sufficient to take the HEX from above string, 
but instead I got the first result ",12," and not the HEX that I want. What have I done wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to use split instead:

```
set result [lindex [split $STRINGTOPARSE ","] 5]
```

`regexp` is not giving you the result you are looking for because the first part that matches is `,12,` and the match stops there and won't look for more matches.

You could use `regexp` to do it, but it will be more messy... one possible way would be to match each comma:

```
regexp {^(?:[^,]*,){5}([0-9A-F]+),} $STRINGTOPARSE -> hex
```

Where `(?:[^,]*,){5}` matches the first 5 non-comma parts with their commas, and `([0-9A-F]+)` then grabs the hex value you're looking for.

---

I think that the problem is that you seem to think `[0-9A-Z]` will have to match at least a letter, which is not the case. it will match any character within the character class and you get a match as long as you get 1 character to match.

If you wanted a regex to match a series of characters with both numbers and letters, then you would have to use some lookaheads (using classes alone might make it more messy):

```
regexp {\y(?=[^,A-Z]*[0-9])(?=[^,0-9]*[A-Z])[0-9A-Z]+\y} $STRINGTOPARSE -> hex
```

But... this might look even more complex than before, so I would advise sticking to splitting instead :)

Comment: Then again, hex values may contain numbers only, or letters only... So the last regex is not really suitable.

Comment: +1. If you know you need the 6th comma-separated field, use `split`. `12` is of course a valid hex number.